# Kivy, create MDChip from user TextField input

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

thank you for your time.
I have an APP I'm working on. I'm trying to automate something where every word I write in the `MDTextField id: sent` is turned into it's own `MDChip id: chip` to be selected later on by the user.

The closest I've gotten is using this:

```
class Main(Screen):
    """main application goes here"""
    def my_callback(dt):
        def __init__(self):
            sent = self.ids.sentence.text.lower()
            print(sent)
            for word in sent.split():
                c = MDChip(label=word, icon='check')
                self.ids.chip.add_widget(c)

    Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 0.5)
```

But it doesn't work. def **init**(self) never actually runs it seems... idk... I have verified that the `my_callback` function is getting called properly by the Clock but that's as far as it goes.

Any thoughts anyone..?

Maybe there is a better function inside Kivy that is called anytime something is typed in a textfield?? That would be perfect I think...

Ultimately I want to use one of the `MDChip` selected by the user and replace their sentence with a new word. I truly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_callback()` method is just defining another method named `__init__()`, without actually calling that new method. That is an `inner function` and is not visible outside of `my_callback()`.

Try changing `my_callback()` to:

```
    def my_callback(self, dt):
        sent = self.ids.sentence.text.lower()
        print(sent)
        for word in sent.split():
            c = MDChip(label=word, icon='check')
            self.ids.chip.add_widget(c)
```

Also, an `__init__()` method is the method used to initialize a `Widget`, and it's not good programming practice to use that method name for other purposes.

Comment: John, you're right. I actually already tried:
```def my_callback(self, dt):```
But it gave me an error cause I didn't know how to call the function with the:
```Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 0.5)``` Seems like the Clock schedule_intervals always passes a 'dt' variable so I am confused on how to pass a "self" arg to my_callback(self, dt):

Comment: The `self` argument is automatically added when you call a method that is an instance method. So, from the code you posted, it appears that `my_callback()` is a method of the `Main` class. Calling `my_callback()` as defined with a `self` parameter should be done using an instance of `Main`. For example, if you schedule the call to  `my_callback()` from within an instance of `Main`, you should call it as `Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I finally found with some help. Thanks all.

```
class Main(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.call)

    def call(self, *args):
        self.ids.stack.clear_widgets()
        sent = self.ids.sentence.text.lower()
        for word in sent.split():
            c = MDChip(label=word,
                       callback=self.do_something,
                       icon='checkbox-blank-outline',
                       color=[.1, .1, .1, .5],)
            self.ids.stack.add_widget(c)

    def do_something(self, inst, word, *args):
        inst.icon = 'checkbox-marked-outline'

        WORD = word
        print(WORD)
        return WORD
```

Using the `Window.bind` inside the `on_pre_enter` was the most important thing. Then it all worked. Here is my KV code:

```
        MDStackLayout:
            id: stack
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
            padding: dp(8)
            spacing: dp(8)
```